# Android. Java звонки в приложений

Tags: java, android, связь

Здравствуйте ребят, возник такой интересный вопрос у меня в голове. Какими методами или же функциями можно совершать звонки в приложений, не просто стандартные вызовы, а как функция голосовых звонков в WhatsApp, знаю дело не лёгкое и не простое, но попа требует приключений, прошу Вас подсказать в каких направлениях мне плыть. Искал в пространствах интернета но к сожалению ничего не нашел, про это мало где говорится. Заранее не поблагодарю.

Comment: 1)Звнок он для тебя

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какой протокол для голоса собираетесь использовать. Если стандартный GSM тракт, то тут все кисло - можно изменить только интерфейс звонилки и то это через хак (что-то типа эмуляции гарнитуры), а в остальном можно только вызвать звонилку через стандартный `Intent.ACTION_CALL`

А если голос будет ходить через IP то тогда жизнь попроще:

1. Смотрите в сторону [SIP API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)
2. Кроме того есть еще несколько проприетарных API, например [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)